# about the struts2 redirectAction result in struts.xml

Tags: struts2

Can `Struts2 redirectAction result`  transfer a reference type like Person.

my code

```
    <action name="saveAdAction" class="saveAdAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">getAdAction</param>
            <param name="namespace">/</param>
            <param name="person">${person}</param>
        </result>           
    </action>

    <action name="getAdAction" class="getAdAction">     
        <result name="success">/ad/ad.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

the person is an bean in saveAdAction and getAdAction.

when i use saveAdAction the webpage will jump into index.jsp. why?

Answer (score 1):

No, a redirect can only transfer request parameters, just like any regular servlet redirect. So you either have to pass each attribute of person as request parameters, or put the person in the session with a key that you can look up in your next action.

Answer (score 1):

No, This is not possible, with `redirectAction` a new value stack will be created and new instance of Request and Response will be created.

So all your previous data will be lost.There are few ways by which you can transfer data and here are few

1. Save data in session and retrieve it in other action.
2. Pass through Query string which is not possible in your case.
3. Use [message-store-interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/message-store-interceptor.html)

You can choose any of the above option

Comment: But i try in my project ,the redirectAction can transfer an integer data,like this                                                                   <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">getAdAction</param>
    <param name="namespace">/</param>
    <param name="id">${id}</param>
   </result>